# How to pass Messages when I inject MessageApi and use the I18nSupport Trait

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

My controller actions use a custom action that looks like:

```
class ActionWithContext @Inject()(....)
  extends ActionBuilder[ContextAwareRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (ContextAwareRequest[A]) =>                   Future[Result]) = {
  ... 
  }

}

class ContextAwareRequest[A](val context: MyContext, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
```

My controller looks like:

```
import play.api.i18n.{MessagesApi, I18nSupport, Messages}
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
class WebsiteController @Inject() (val messagesApi: MessagesApi, actionWithContext: ActionWithContext, ..)
      extends BaseController with I18nSupport {


    def edit(websiteId: Int)  =  actionWithContext { request =>
        val model = ..
        Ok(views.html.backend.websites.edit(model)(request.context))
      }

    }
```

The view page looks like:

```
@(form: Form[controllers.WebsiteForm])(implicit context: MyContext, m: Messages) {


}
```

I am getting the error:

```
not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit context: com.example.services.components.MyContext, implicit m: play.api.i18n.Messages)play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class edit.
[error] Unspecified value parameter m.
[error]     Ok(views.html.websites.edit(model)(request.context))
[error]
```

I tried passing in the messageApi like:

```
 Ok(views.html.websites.edit(model)(request.context, messageApi))
```

But I then got a type mismatch error between Messages and MessageApi.

What should I be doing?

P.S I am not even using messages in my views, but I am using the Form helpers which I guess use messages under the covers...

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you're trying to pass one implicit parameter explicitly and the other implicitly. You have to either pass them both explicitly:

```
Ok(views.html.websites.edit(model)(request.context, implicitly[Messages]))
```

Or both implicitly:

```
implicit val context = request.context
Ok(views.html.websites.edit(model))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add the 'implicit val context = request.context in myActionWithContext somehow?  Because every action will have this code and if I can avoid adding it to all my actions that would be great.

Comment: You should be able to write a trait that contains something like `implicit def request2Context(implicit request: ContextAwareRequest): MyContext = request.context`, then mix-in that trait similarly to how you're mixing in `I18nSupport`. See this for inspiration: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/I18nSupport.scala#L26

Comment: Or just add that `def` to your `BaseController`.

Comment: If I am not using Messages in my view, why is it expecting it?  It is because of the forms helpers?

Comment: Could I somehow do the implicitly[Messages] in my basecontroller also?  not sure if I can inject in my basecontroller somehow?

Comment: I am getting this error now: `class WebsiteController needs to be abstract, since method messagesApi in trait I18nSupport of type => play.api.i18n.MessagesApi is not defined`

Comment: Try replacing `messagesApi: MessagesApi` with `val messagesApi: MessagesApi` in your `WebsiteController` class definition.

Comment: (As per https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N#Externalizing-messages).

Comment: Still getting the same error after making in a val.